# Euclidean algorithm understanding

Tags: python

when I use the numbers 931 and 301 it correctly puts out 7. But I dont understand why the while function does not terminate one step earlier. The last step the variables look like r0=7, r1=0 and r2=0. The step before they should be r0=21, r1=7 and r2=0. Thus r2 is 0, the while function should not calculate one more stept and actually r1=7 should be the bcd and not r0. Thanks for help.

python code:

```
print('find biggest common divisor')
print('bigger number:')
r0 = input()
print('smaller number:')
r1 = input()
r0 = int(r0)
r1 = int(r1)
r2 = 1
while r2 != 0:    
    r2 = r0 % r1
    r0 = r1
    r1 = r2
print('bcd is ' + str(r0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the values wrong. `r2` is `7` in the previous step:

```
...
while r2 != 0:    
    r2 = r0 % r1
    r0 = r1
    r1 = r2
    print("r0: " + str(r0) +", r1: " + str(r1) + ", r2: " + str(r2))
print('bcd is ' + str(r0))
```

outputs:

```
find biggest common divisor
bigger number:
931
smaller number:
301
r0: 931, r1: 301, r2: 1
r0: 301, r1: 28, r2: 28
r0: 28, r1: 21, r2: 21
r0: 21, r1: 7, r2: 7
r0: 7, r1: 0, r2: 0
bcd is 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot! This was my first program, so sorry that I didnt see the easy solution to just print out the values to see the error. The following works like intended now.

```
print('find biggest common divisor')
print('bigger number:')
r0 = input()
print('smaller number:')
r1 = input()
r0 = int(r0)
r1 = int(r1)
r2 = r0 % r1
# print("r0: " + str(r0) +", r1: " + str(r1) + ", r2: " + str(r2))
while r2 != 0:
    r0 = r1    
    r1 = r2
    r2 = r0 % r1
    # print("r0: " + str(r0) +", r1: " + str(r1) + ", r2: " + str(r2))
print('bcd is ' + str(r1))
```